# Try install linux from usb, os load and computer reboot

Tags: boot, live-usb, menu

i try to rescue a old computer win a broken winXp (not rescue the windows ... juste make a full install linux ... )

i try different thing, with alwayse same result.

Put iso on ubs stick with etcher...
Plug and boot on the usb stick...

i try with ubuntu, debian, debian net install, and Bodhi ( and memtest )

i can load the menu for select what i need to do, like start live os, graphical install, text install ect ...

but whatever choice i do, the computer seem to load the files, and reboot on the usb stick ....

i think is a somethink in bios or some argument needed to boot properly, do you have any idea ?

( i try with "nolapic noapic" without realy understand wath this argument do , but no progress at all )

Answer (score 0):

On some bios-es, it's possible to set the search sequence between devices, eg.

```
USB,CDROM,HD
```

will look for a usb stick, then cd-drive followed by Hard Disk.
If it were set to only 
    HD

Then the USB and cd-drive would not be searched.

Getting into the bios depends on the version, <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> are common keys to press during the boot process, to break into the BIOS. Perhaps others could suggest other keys that allow access.

Alternatively, just remove the USB stick before it is read during reboot and see if it boots from the hard drive.

Comment: i only set usb stick and hdd in sequence boot ....
but i can understand how its work, if systeme reboot, ram is reset too ...
So why computer reboot when i choose to boot on graphical or text install mod on the first menu ? ( of the usb live, not the bios )